# TypeScript not calling one of the class methods

Tags: typescript

i have a ts class which implements an interface with 2 functions and has these 2 functions implemented. then i have a variable typed with this interface which gets the only this class's object. then i'm using this variable in different event handlers and calling one of these 2 functions in each, but somewhy one of the functions works perfect, but the 2nd one isn't being called at all, without any error messages and halting code execution - the next line after the func call still gets executed

here's the code:

screen.ts:

```
export interface Screen {
    controller: Controller;

    trySimulate(e: KeyboardEvent): boolean;
    receive(data: any);
}
```

screens/world.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../screen.ts"/> 

export class World implements Screen {
    controller: Controller;
    waitingForRespond: boolean;
    map: Map;
    me: Player;
    players: Player[];

    // this function doesn't work
    trySimulate = function (e: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
        if (e.keyCode >= 47 && e.keyCode <= 50) {
            this.waitingForRespond = true;
            var dir: Direction = e.keyCode - 47;
            return this.me.moveTo(dir);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // this function works
    receive = function (data: any) {
        this.waitingForRespond = false;


    }
}
```

controller.ts:

```
export class Controller {
    receiveServerData = function (e: MessageEvent) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
        controller.screens[msg.target].receive(msg);
    }

    keyPressed = function (e: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (controller.currentScreen.trySimulate(e)) {
            ...
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

i set a breakpoint on the line

```
if (controller.currentScreen.trySimulate(e)) {
```

and it got triggered, but when i pressed f11 (step in), it skipped func call and moved straight to the return true; line - why?

Comment: Can you please show more of your code? also, is there a reason why the class methods are like that instead of `trySimulate(e: KeyboardEvent): boolean { ... }`?

Comment: what part of the code do u want? and i tried that way of declaration, but it gives the same result

Comment: The entire class may help, if it's too big then just what's relevant.

Comment: just pasted more code

Comment: Where do you run it? How do you transpile it? Are you sure it isn't running a cached version instead?

Comment: VS2015's typescript project which compiles everything and redirects to ff, which has developer tools on f12 which show all the .ts files with possibility to set breakpoints in them and check the variables' values - it shows all variables having the right values, including controller.currentScreen having a World object

Comment: What's `controller`? do you have a global variable of that name?

Comment: for now yes, but if there's a better way to share a singleton object with event handlers, i'll use it

Comment: Ok, before the `if` add this: `console.log(controller, controller.currentScreen)` what do you get?

Comment: i got <unavailable> <unavailable>

Comment: i got <unavailable> <unavailable> in receiveServerData too - what does this <unavailable> mean?

Comment: are you sure that your `controller` instance has been instantiated?

Comment: but i got <unavailable> <unavailable> from receiveServerData too, when i pasted the console.log call there, and it still works - and it can't be not initialized, i'm setting onkeydown event handler in a controller.Initialize() call